# Spring (3.x) property injection in multi-module (Maven multi-module) mode

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependency-injection

How to inject properties inside individual Maven module using spring property injection and Spring's component scan?

Comment: Found a solution. Spring property injection is not working if you try to set properties in each spring-config file in each and every Maven module. 

For example if you have three maven modules and if you use;

<context:property-placeholder location="location of your file"/>

in each and every module spring fail to inject properties yet least it fails randomly and it leaves very less information about this in logs.

To curb this use the "property-placeholder" in one single config file. This will make sure you have one single ProperyPlaceholderConfigurer per Webapplication context.

Thanks

Comment: You could really post this as an answer yourself and mark it as the best.